# Display a PNG favicon in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I show a PNG favicon in CakePHP? I'm currently using `$this->Html->meta('icon')` but it looks for `.ico` in the root. How do I change it so that it looks for `.png`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$this->Html->meta('icon', $this->Html->url('/favicon.png'));
```

Comment: For CakePHP 3.x it will be `$this->Url->build('/favicon.png')` instead of `$this->Html->url()`

Answer (score 8):

This would be better to use:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico','img/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon'));
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

CakePHP 3.5:

`echo $this->Html->meta('icon', 'favicon.png', ['type'=>'image/png'])`

will generate

```
<link href="/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="icon"/>
<link href="/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the icon into the /img/ folder - it just wouldn't accept it in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should put your favicon.ico inside webroot folder, cakephp framework will do rest of the things by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the `$this->html->meta('icon')` from the default layout,

this worked for me